# extract last 10 elements from xml document

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

i'm trying to extract the last 10 in elements from my xml document, am using this code to parse it :

```
slideView.ItemsSource = 
    from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("album") 
    let id = channel.Element("catid")
    let tit = channel.Element("name")
    let des = channel.Element("picture")
    orderby (int) id descending 
    select new onair
    {
        title = tit == null ? null : tit.Value,
        photo = des == null ? null : des.Value,
    };
```

help please :)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will return last 10 elements ordered by `catid`:

```
slideView.ItemsSource = 
    xmlItems.Descendants("album") 
            .OrderByDescending(channel => (int)channel.Element("catid"))
            .Select(channel => new onair
            {
                title = (string)channel.Element("name"),
                photo = (string)channel.Element("picture")
            }).Take(10);
```

Same with query syntax (well, almost query syntax - there is no keyword for Take operator):

```
slideView.ItemsSource = 
    (from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("album")     
     orderby (int)channel.Element("catid") descending 
     select new onair
     {
         title = (string)channel.Element("name"),
         photo = (string)channel.Element("picture")
     }).Take(10);
```

Comment: thanks, that worked well but i'am trying to add a button that load the next 10 elements if the user clicks on it since i have many elemnts on the xml :/ any ideas please?

Comment: @MeriemBenMrad you can use `Skip(pageIndex*pageSize).Take(pageSize)`

Comment: can you explain more and give me an example please.?

Comment: @MeriemBenMrad google for [paging with LINQ](http://hurtsmybrains.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/paging-with-linq/)

Comment: i don't think that i can deal here with paging because i get the hole xml document from the first request..so is there any way to just extract with every click the next 10 elemnts? thanks

Comment: @MeriemBenMrad you need whole xml for paging. If you have some problems with paging implementation, then you can ask question on SO. Sorry, don't have time now.